# MvcContrib Grid for editing only some columns

Tags: mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I Have a view:

```
<% Html.Grid(Model.InnerModel.OrderRecords)
    .Empty("No data available")
    .Attributes(new Hash(id => "RoadReportResultsTable"))
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(x => x.OrderNumber);
        column.For(x => x.DateReceived);
        column.For(x => x.TotalCount);
        column.For(x => x.DateSent);
        column.For(x => x.SentCount);
        column.For(x => x.Comments);
    }).Render();
%>
```

I need to make only the Comments column editable, so the user can only enter the Comments, but can't edit any of the other columns.

I want to open a popup on Comments Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my project I use this code to add action link to column:

```
column.For(group => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { appId = Model.ApplicationId, id = group.Id }, null))
        .Encode(false)
        .Sortable(false);
```